# Как вывести слова начинающиеся на гласную букву

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу: как вывести слова из стихотворения, где слово начинается на гласную букву.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
  String str="Никогда не забуду (он был, или не был,\n" +
                

"Этот вечер): пожаром зари\n" +
               
 "Сожжено и раздвинуто бледное небо,\n" +
              
  "И на жёлтой заре — фонари.\n" +
                "\n" +
                
"Я сидел у окна в переполненном зале.\n" +
                
"Где-то пели смычки о любви.\n" +
                
"Я послал тебе чёрную розу в бокале\n" +
                
"Золотого, как нёбо, аи.\n" +
                "\n" +
               
 "Ты взглянула. Я встретил смущённо и дерзко\n" +
               
 "Взор надменный и отдал поклон.\n" +
             
   "Обратясь к кавалеру, намеренно резко\n" +
               
 "Ты сказала: «И этот влюблён».\n" +
                "\n" +
               
 "И сейчас же в ответ что-то грянули струны,\n" +
               
 "Исступлённо запели смычки…\n" +
               
 "Но была ты со мной всем презрением юным,\n" +
                
"Чуть заметным дрожаньем руки…\n" +
                "\n" +
             
   "Ты рванулась движеньем испуганной птицы,\n" +
              
  "Ты прошла, словно сон мой легка…\n" +
                
"И вздохнули духи, задремали ресницы,\n" +
               
 "Зашептались тревожно шелка.\n" +
                "\n" +
               
 "Но из глуби зеркал ты мне взоры бросала\n" +
                
"И, бросая, кричала: «Лови!..»\n" +
                
"А монисто бренчало, цыганка плясала\n" +
              
  "И визжала заре о любви.";
       

 String[]ar={"a","o","u","y","e","я","и",};
       
 for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)

        System.out.println(str.startsWith((ar[i])));
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуй сначала самостоятельно. Будут проблемы - поможем.

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуй удалить ненужные символы из строки.
2. Раздели строку на слова.
3. Итерируйся по словам и проверяй, что они начинаются на гласную букву, если условие верно - выводи.

Код не прикрепляю, чтобы была возможность сделать самому.

Comment: if ((str.charAt(0)=='a')||(str.charAt(0)=='e')||(str.charAt(0)=='и')||(str.charAt(0)=='у')||(str.charAt(0)=='о'));

        System.out.println(str);

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй регулярным выражением. В данном случае будет что-то типа такого;
`(^|\s+)([УЕЫЁАОЯИЮаеёыуоэяию])([А-я]*)`
Для этого почитай про `Pattern` и `Matcher` в Java, по идее такой подход будет достаточно лёгок в реализации, универсален и будет быстро работать

Comment: Спасибо ,действительно с  регулярным выражением легче